# Why is my CSV file coming out empty after code runs w/no errors?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am very new to coding and was trying to get a basic webscraping code to work. The code works just fine, the problem is that I cannot get the CSV file to have any information on it. Any help would be appreciated.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

import csv

page_to_scrape = requests.get("https://www.scrapethissite.com/pages/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_to_scrape.text, "html.parser")
descriptions = soup.findAll("p", attrs=("class" == "lead session-desc"))
titles = soup.findAll("h3", attrs=("class" == "page-title"))

with open("scrapeinformation.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)

    for title, desc in zip(titles, descriptions):
        print(title.text + " - " + desc.text)
        thewriter.writerow([title.text, desc.text])
f.close()
```

Comment: Why are you formatting your python code as javascript?

Comment: When I run your code the CSV file is not empty i.e. "I cannot get the CSV file to have any information on it".  Side note--you don't need f.close() at the end since you are using file context manager via the with statement.

Comment: I ran your code as-is and it worked, I got a CSV file with 5 rows and 2 columns. Maybe try printing `descriptions` and `titles` and make sure those lists have data; if they don't, you'll create the empty CSV file but never write a row. And, yeah, you don't need `f.close()` since you're using the `with open(...` context. Welcome, and good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you absolutely *sure* the csv is empty? When I ran your code, I noticed that the file *looked* empty when I viewed on Excel, but not if I opened with notepad or Google Sheets, and also that `print(title.text + " - " + desc.text)` shows that the cell entries are surrounded in a lot of whitespace.

So, actually the Excel cells are just showing the whitespace at the beginning because the default format doesn't show more than what fits in the cell. I can see the contents after I:

1. Select All by pressing `Ctrl`+`A`, and then
2. Toggle the [Wrap Text](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wrap-text-in-a-cell-2a18cff5-ccc1-4bce-95e4-f0d4f3ff4e84) setting by pressing `Alt` + `H` + `W` (try toggling once more if there seems to be no difference the first time)

However, the approach I would personally recommend here is to **remove** the whitespaces in the first place - you can do so by using the [`strip()` method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) (like `.text.strip()`) or by using `.get_text(strip=True)` instead of `.text`.